# Convenient way to convert vector<string> to vector<double>

Tags: c++

Is there any convenient way in C++ to convert a vector to a vector other than using transform algorithm and istringstream?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: What is not convenient about `transform`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`lexical_cast` is quite "convenient".

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
  vec2.push_back(boost::lexical_cast<double>(vec[i]));
}
```

Of course this becomes even more fun with `std::transform`:

```
std::transform(strings.begin(), strings.end(), 
               std::back_inserter(doubles), 
               boost::lexical_cast<double, std::string>); // Note the two template arguments!
```

`atof` could also fit your needs, remember to include `cstdlib`:

```
std::transform(strings.begin(), strings.end(), std::back_inserter(doubles), 
               [](const std::string& x) { return std::atof(x.c_str()); });
```

Comment: thank you. Actually what I want is not to use boost, just core C++. :)

Comment: Then `istringstream` it is. Or maybe `atof`.

Comment: thank you for the atof solution. BTW, what is it called for `[](const std::string& x) { return std::atof(x.c_str()); }`? Looks like an anonymous function. I haven't seen this in C++ before.

Comment: @Qiang Li That's exactly what it is. It's a part of the upcoming C++0x standard and most modern compilers support it. I just used it for the sake of brevity. A normal functor could do the same.

Comment: thanks. Not familiar with c++0x yet. Just recalled it from python